# IDA: close without saving changes

Tags: ida, idapython

In my work, I often end up with lots of IDA windows open concurrently. Once done with analysis, I would like to close them all. It is relatively easy to issue a command to all of them simultaneously e.g. using a bridge. My problems come about when trying to close all of them without saving changes (e.g. if I ran some scripts on all of the IDA tasks and messed up).

Unfortunately, `qexit` saves all changes made. Sending a kill command does prevent saving, but risks corruption. I'm left to close all of the processes one by one from the UI, which is tedious (click X, click don't save, click ok, repeat). Is there a better way (short of an autoclicker) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set_database_flag(DBFL_KILL)`